# where to see sparkjobserver main console output?

Tags: apache-spark, stdout, spark-jobserver

When running spark-submit, you can see the println statements right in the shell. When submitting a spark job to the sparkjobserver, I can't find where the stdout messages go. Anyone knows that?

Comment: Did you check in /var/log/spark-jobserver/current file ?

Answer (score 0):

I found it in
/mnt/var/log/spark-jobserver/spark-job-server.log

Comment: Unfortunateley, it does not have the driver stdout. so this question is still open.